# How do i return a function call to an aframe text box element

Tags: javascript, aframe

so i'm trying to use a function to return a text to my aframe element, so far here's my attempt

```
<script>
ggfunction(){
  return "yourcall";
}

</script>
```

and

```
<a-marker smooth="true" type="barcode" value="1">
<a-text value=ggfunction() position="0 1 6" rotation="-90 0 0" material="color: white" align="center"></a-text>
</a-marker>
```

but it just returns ggfunction() instead of the text "yourcall"

Answer (score 1):

HTML standard doesn't allow inlined JavaScript. You can for instance write a [component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#registering-the-component-with-aframe-registercomponent) and set the attribute in the `init` method. [glitch illustrating](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/soapy-complex-deposit)